# GCC package requires a package which is not for my PC architecture

Tags: apt, dependencies, gcc

When I try

`sudo apt install gcc`

it gives

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libatomic1 : Depends: gcc-12-base (= 12-20220319-1ubuntu1) but 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 is to be installed
 libcc1-0 : Depends: gcc-12-base (= 12-20220319-1ubuntu1) but 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 is to be installed
 libitm1 : Depends: gcc-12-base (= 12-20220319-1ubuntu1) but 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 is to be installed
 liblsan0 : Depends: gcc-12-base (= 12-20220319-1ubuntu1) but 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 is to be installed
 libquadmath0 : Depends: gcc-12-base (= 12-20220319-1ubuntu1) but 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 is to be installed
 libubsan1 : Depends: gcc-12-base (= 12-20220319-1ubuntu1) but 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

So, I have 12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04 while gcc requires 12-20220319-1ubuntu1. When I try to update gcc-12-base it says

`gcc-12-base is already the newest version (12.1.0-2ubuntu1~22.04).`

I have searched gcc-12-base package at packages.ubuntu.com and found [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83zvU.png) My PC's architecture is AMD64 and the version which gcc package requires is not for AMD64. What should I do?

Output of `sudo apt update`:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

Output of `sudo apt upgrade`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I tried `sudo aptitude why-not gcc` which outputs

```
i   libdpkg-perl Suggests   gcc | c-compiler          
p   gcc          Suggests   flex                      
p   flex:i386    Provides   flex                      
p   flex:i386    Recommends gcc:i386 | c-compiler:i386
p   gcc:i386     Conflicts  gcc
```

Comment: How is it that your system only has one line for sources? What happened to the other sources?  Did you add 32-bit architecture to your PC at some point?

Comment: The default gcc is 11, so why did the 12 get picked up?  Have you enabled the Developer Options for Jammy Proposed?

Comment: @ubfan1 no, I haven't

Comment: `apt-cache policy gcc` please.

Comment: gcc:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1
  Version table:
     4:11.2.0-1ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages

Comment: Restore your Ubuntu package sources please.  Search for this here l'm on mobile.